# Modifying JavaScript array properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, express

I'm using Express and have an array of objects.  I would like to modify the `created` property (I am using dateFormat package) for presentation.

The array is the result of a mongo query and is assigned to a variable `stories` and looks like:

```
[
    { public: false,
      keyStageLevel: [ 'ks1' ],
      created: 2018-03-25T13:01:30.809Z,
      _id: 5ab79daafa832035b416536f,
      slug: 'goldilocks',
      name: 'Goldilocks',
      comments: null,
      id: '5ab79daafa832035b416536f' },
    { public: false,
      keyStageLevel: [ 'ks1' ],
     created: 2018-03-25T13:07:22.421Z,
     _id: 5ab79f0afa832035b4165370,
     slug: 'cinderella',
     name: 'Cinderella',    
     comments: null,
     id: '5ab79f0afa832035b4165370' },
   ..
]
```

If I execute

```
stories.map(function(story){
    story.created = dateFormat(story.created, "dddd, mmmm dS, yyyy, h:MM:ss TT")
    console.log('AFTER TRANSFORM '+story.created);
});
```

The console.log shows the date format I want but the `story.created` values in the `stories` array is unmodified.  What is the correct way (ES5 if possible, I'm learning and I find it easier to understand what is going on) to reformat the `created` property in the `stories` array?

Edit - showing the query and use of `.map` and `.foreach` both of which leave `stories' unmodified

```
let stories = await Story.find({$or:[{'group': {$in:group}}, 
  {'public':true} ]})
    .populate('group')
    .populate('createdBy');
console.log('BEFORE TRANSFORM '+stories);
// console.log(stories);
// stories.map(function(story){
//     story.created = dateFormat(story.created, "dddd, mmmm dS, yyyy, h:MM:ss TT")
//     console.log('AFTER TRANSFORM '+story.created);
// });
stories.forEach(story => {
    story.created = dateFormat(story.created, "dddd, mmmm dS, yyyy, h:MM:ss TT")
});
console.log('AFTER TRANSFORM '+stories);
```

Comment: `.map` expects a `return` value - do a `forEach` - `stories.forEach(function(story){`

Comment: Assuming you do not assigne the result of `stories.map` to a variable, where and how do you check the values in the `stories`? Create a minimal and reproducable example.

Comment: @tymeJV I agree that `.forEach` shoudl be use here. But it would not explain the problem the OP has. Because if the OP would do `stories = stories.map`  then  `stories` would be an array containing only `undefined`, but the OP says that the values are unchanged.  And if the OP really wrote `stories.map` without asigning the new array to a variable, then result of `stories.map` and `stories.forEach`, would be the same.

Comment: I agree @t.niese - I'm guessing OP has some more code that may be affecting this that we're not seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others note, you're misusing `map`.  My choice, though, would be to use `map` properly, and create a new array from your old one.  I think it's much easier to reason about data that is not mutated.  Here's one way to do that:

```js
const stories = [{"_id": "5ab79daafa832035b416536f", "comments": null, "created": "2018-03-25T13:01:30.809Z", "id": "5ab79daafa832035b416536f", "keyStageLevel": ["ks1"], "name": "Goldilocks", "public": false, "slug": "goldilocks"}, {"_id": "5ab79f0afa832035b4165370", "comments": null, "created": "2018-03-25T13:07:22.421Z", "id": "5ab79f0afa832035b4165370", "keyStageLevel": ["ks1"], "name": "Cinderella", "public": false, "slug": "cinderella"}]

const dateFormat = (d) => d.slice(0, 10) // dummy

const updatedStories = 
    stories.map(story => ({...story, created: dateFormat(story.created)}))

console.log(updatedStories)
```

If that ES6 bothers you, then you could replace it with

```
stories.map(story => Object.assign({}, story, {created: dateFormat(story.created)}))
```

Comment: Many thanks to everyone for their answers and discussion.  I'm marking this one as the answer because it works for me

Answer (score -1):

You may wanna consider `forEach()`:

```
stories.forEach(story => {
    story.created = dateFormat(story.created, "dddd, mmmm dS, yyyy, h:MM:ss TT")
});
```

**Docs:** [`Array.prototype.forEach()` - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: This would not explain `but the story.created values in the stories array is unmodified`. If the `return story;` would be the problem then the OP would have a list of `undefined` and not of unchanged story objects.

Comment: This is really missleading. `stories.map` does not change the original array, that's true, but `story.created = ...` will still have an effect on the element that is stored in `stories`. So `stories.map(story => {  story.created = ... ; return story; });` and stories.forEach(story => {  story.created = ...; }` has the same effect on the `story.created` of the elements in `stories`. Check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ryybztgp/4/)

Comment: *.map returns a new array with changes and the original array remains unchanged* your approach is mutating the original array's objects.

Comment: @t.niese I see what you mean, thanks for your input. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @Ele Thanks for your input, I have updated my answer.